# returning concatenation instead of addition in python IDE

Tags: python

```
x = input("Enter the first number!")
y = input("Enter the second number!")
z = input("Enter the third number!")

def adding(a, b, c):
    s = a+b+c
    return s

c = adding(x, y, z)
print(c)
```

I've tried a program of addition in python IDE, but instead of printing sum it returns concatenation of numbers as strings.

I don't know what's wrong with it?

Anybody have any idea?

Sorry! for a dumb question.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Comment: You just need to cast your input to an integer. Use `int(input("Enter your number!"))`, though this won't handle errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your input is in a string form and you need it to be in an int (or float) form.

```
def input_number(message):
    return int(input(message))

x = input_number("Enter the first number!")
y = input_number("Enter the second number!")
z = input_number("Enter the third number!")

def adding(a, b, c):
    s = a+b+c
    return s

c = adding(x, y, z)
print(c)
```

Should work nicely for you.

Note: This won't handle errors (say, if the user enters something that isn't a number). If you want your numbers to have decimals simply change the `int` in input_number to a `float`.

Answer (score 6):

`input` by default should get the characters of type string. You need to convert them to integers. If those are floating point numbers, then change `int` in the below code to `float`.

```
def adding(a, b, c):
    s = int(a)+int(b)+int(c)
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

so basically python take all the input as String we have to convert explicit-ally,
in the below code i am converting input as int(casting it)
Using this example you can take the reference for the above problem.

```
def get_sum(data1,data2):
    """this function is responsible to do sum opration of two number , and return back to coller"""
    return (data1+data2)

def get_as_number_int(msg):
    """this function is responsible to take input as integer and retunr back to coller"""
    return int(input(msg))

data1=get_as_number_int("Please enter data1 value")
data2=get_as_number_int("Please enter data2 value")

print("sum of input : ",get_sum(data1,data2))
```